# How to solve this syntax question

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

Hello guys could anyone help me in solving these questions in syntax

the sentence ;   John's discussion of the riots in the meeting suddenly put all physics students right into huge turmoil.

ps; I am curious about the argument that supports each component of n'v'p through an empirical basis.

2. 1) What is the basis for supporting the claim that the -V category should be included in the It ~ that emphasis statement?

2) I wonder if there is a counterexample to this, and if so, is it just like that, or is it genuine?

Comment: Your first question is not clear. What do you mean by "It ~"?

Comment: Others are voting to close your question, if you don't act and amend it, put it in another clear shape, it'll be closed.